# highlighting pgn substrings on click

Tags: javascript, chess

Second time writing here.

I have a string and a button. This string is in pgn format (that stands for portable notation game) and so contains the list of moves of a chess game. It is made in this way:

```
<p> 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Bc4 ... {this is the comment of current move} ... Bc5</p>
```

Now, I have to highlight first e4 then e5 then Nf3........ And I have to do this on click every time the button is clicked.
I do not ask for a ready solution nor how to make not highlight also the comments, the dots and the numbers but just if someone would like to give me an input to start thinking to the solution.

Thank you and bye

Comment: Please include all the code you have so we know where you're at.

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: Actually, the following was good for me. I will try to code something myself and probably I will add here later

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the pgn is correct and that all moved in it are legal. Then I would on the first click go through the list until I find the "1. ", then I know that the next word is the given move. Then on 2nd click you find the next word which will be blacks response. On 3rd you search for "2. ", and so on.

Do you want to highlight the move's start and end position, or just the ending square?

1. If you just want to highlight the end square it will always be the last 2 characters in the string (except for castling, en passant, promotions, checks, and check mate. These will have to be checked differently in an if statement.
2. If you want to also include the start position of the piece then I think you need to write your own move generator and compare all legal moves in the position with the given end square.
   Maybe you can do some logic with the end square given that you know what type of piece was moved. For example if you have a knight move, e.g. Nf6, you can check all squares around to see if you find a knight one knight move away. This will be lots of checks though so I think you will be better off creating a simple move generator.

I hope it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, I will read and read again with attention, but I think that I understood. :) Bye!